# Prometheus rate returns 0 when same observation for a while

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm using Prometheus to show graphs in grafana.

One of my metrics is a histogram called api_duration_milliseconds which I use like this:

```
sum(rate(api_duration_milliseconds_sum[5m])) by (url) / sum(rate(api_duration_milliseconds_count[5m])) by (url)
```

but the rate function may return 0 when my observations have the same value for a while.
How can I resolve this? For example, if I just started sending the metrics and only has 1 observation - 20ms. I would want to see 20ms and not 0.

One thing that may help is to first aggregate the data from all machines that send the metrics (between all of them I have less chance of having the same value) and then applying the rate method. but I was not sure how to do this.

Comment: Why do you need to resolve this? And what kind of result do you expect? Rate equal to 0 for a constant seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: And regarding your "first aggregate ... then applying the rate ": [don't](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edited my question:
"For example, if I just started sending the metrics and only has 1 observation - 20ms. I would want to see 20ms and not 0."
Or if I have 1 observation from multiple machines, I want to aggregate all of them and not get 0 for their rate

Comment: Yes, prometheus' functions for counter behave somewhat unexpectedly around "start of counting". And AFAIK, there is no easy and convenient way to work around this.